# Xamarin Forms MVVM (Prism) with Media.Plugin - How to get a taken picture from device storage

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism

**I am using Xamarin Forms PCL (MVVM Prism) with MediaPlugin** (https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin).

I have a viewModel with a public property called ImagePath

```
private string imagePath;
public string ImagePath
{
   get { return imagePath; }
   set { SetProperty(ref imagePath, value, "ImagePath"); }
}
```

in my XAML i have:

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100"/>
```

When i set a image url (from web) to ImagePath property, it works without problems. (I am setting an string like this: "http://www.myaddress.com/myimage.jpg")

But, when I take a picture using the following code (MediaPlugin):

```
var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
            {
                Directory = "Sample",
                Name = "test.jpg"
            });

ImagePath = file.Path;

// also tried: ImagePath = ImageSource.FromFile(file.Path).toString();
```

the var **file.Path** receives a value like this:

"/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/{APPNAME}.Android/files/Pictures/{DIRECTORYNAME}/{IMAGENAME}"

With this **file.Path** value then i'm setting ImagePath property:
ImagePath = file.Path;

But the taken image does not appear on the screen.

I also have tried to use the
Image.Source property as suggested in MediaPlugin docs, however i have not reached the result i want.

I also have tried the following:

Public property into VM:

```
private Image image = new Image();
        public Image Image
        {
            get { return image; }
            set { SetProperty(ref image, value, "Image"); }
        }
```

Xaml:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Image.Source}" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100"/>
```

After set file value (as showed before):

```
image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
                    {
                        var stream = file.GetStream();
                        file.Dispose();
                        return stream;
                    });
```

Is there any way to make it work?
Thanks!!

Comment: Hello, i am having the same issue and i just wonder do you still have access to this solution with solved answer? The answer below is no good for me, i still cant see the picture.So maybe i am doing it wrong.

Comment: Same issue here. Setting image source from property of item in observable collection in view model, but no image shows. I'm trying to display an image taken by app (not an embedded resource). Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Media Plugin returns a MediaFile.

I store this in a class I use for storage and display

```
public class IncidentImage
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int IncidentDetailsId { get; set; }

    public byte[] ImageBytes { get; set; }

    [Ignore]
    public ImageSource ImageSource
    {
        get
        {
            ImageSource retval = null;
            if (ImageBytes != null)
            {
                retval = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(ImageBytes));
            }
            return retval;
        }
    }
}
```

Like this

```
    var incidentImage = new IncidentImage
    {
        ImageBytes = image.ToByteArray()
    };
```

image being the MediaFile returned by the plugin.

Then my XAML looks like this

```
<Image Source="{Binding IncidentImage.ImageSource}" Aspect="AspectFit"  />
```

You could also do it by moving the ImageSource code to a converter.

Comment: Great, it worked!!
do you have any tib about to post this ImageSource type to a sql database? or would be better to save the file and upload it?

Comment: I save the IncidentImage type to a local Sqlite database and also upload it via a REST API service

Answer (score 0):

Hi Steve I do what do you said but, i don't display my photo the first issue y had its the `image.ToByteArray()`

i resolve it with that code

```
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
file.GetStream().CopyTo(memoryStream);
file.Dispose();

var incidentImage = new IncidentImage
 {
   ImageBytes = memoryStream.ToArray()
 };`
```