# MVVM Media Plugin not displaying picture

Tags: xamarin.forms

i need help with media plugin. I can see that the picture is taken however it doesnt display inthe content page.  While debugging the app i can see the path but the picture is not there I have tried to follow this solution, [Xamarin Forms MVVM (Prism) with Media.Plugin - How to get a taken picture from device storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47441800/xamarin-forms-mvvm-prism-with-media-plugin-how-to-get-a-taken-picture-from-d)
And this solution
[Capturing and updating an image source using MVVM in Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52836842/capturing-and-updating-an-image-source-using-mvvm-in-xamarin)
however still nothing. My Binding works fine for everything. Just I dont know how to get the image

```
 <Image
                                    x:Name="Photo"
                                    Grid.Row="2"
                                    HeightRequest="100"
                                    Source="{Binding postViewModel.ImageSource}"
                                    VerticalOptions="Start" />

ViewModel

Ctor

 public PostViewModel()
        {
            TakePictureCommand = new Command(async () => await TakePicture());
        }


private async Task TakePicture()
        {
            await Permission();
            var imageSource = await DependencyService.Get<IMessage>().ShowActionSheet(AppResources.AlertPhoto, AppResources.AlertNewPhoto, AppResources.AlertGallery);
            if (imageSource == AppResources.AlertNewPhoto)
            {
                var imageFileName = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions()
                {
                    Name = $"{DateTime.UtcNow}.jpg",
                    DefaultCamera = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.CameraDevice.Rear,
                    PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Medium,
                    SaveToAlbum = true
                });
                if (imageFileName == null)
                {
                    DependencyService.Get<IMessage>().LongAlert(AppResources.AlertNoAcess);
                }
                else
                {
                 
                    ImageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => imageFileName.GetStream());
                    var test = ImageSource;
                }
                

            }

Master VM BInding

   protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            BindingContext = MasterPostsView= new MasterPostsViewModel();
   
        }

  class MasterPostsViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public PostViewModel postViewModel { get; set; }
        public CategoriesViewModel categoriesViewModel { get; set; }

        public MasterPostsViewModel(INavigation navigation)
        {
            postViewModel = new PostViewModel();

            categoriesViewModel = new CategoriesViewModel();
           
        }
    }

Have tried also
  public string ImageSource { get => _imageSource; set { _imageSource = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }

 ImageSource = imageFileName.AlbumPath;

 
I have 
     protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
```

Comment: set your `ImageSource` property to the **path** of the image

Comment: can you please show what you mean

Comment: bind your Image's `Source` property to the file path of the image (a string).  Also be sure your VM is implementing INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: Please see my update

Comment: Could you get the data `ImageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => imageFileName.GetStream());` ?

Comment: No, still nothing. well i  saw there is not empty however i still nothing on display

Comment: Could you show the complete PostViewModel ？

Comment: If you want i can send you a link to my repo

Comment: @jojojojojo ok,i will test it.